# No funcionan los discos de filesystem

Tags: laravel, filesystem

Estoy teniendo problemas para acceder a los directorios que tengo declarados en el filesystem. Tengo varios discos, con sus respectivos symbolic links:

```
 'disks' => [
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'documentos' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/documentos'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'private',
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'proffesionalImg' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/proffesionalImg'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'staffImg' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/staffImg'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
    
    'articleImg' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/articleImg'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],

    'eventosImg' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/eventosImg'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],



    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        'throw' => false,
    ],

],

'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('proffesionalImg') => storage_path('app/proffesionalImg'),
    public_path('staffImg') => storage_path('app/staffImg'),
    public_path('articleImg') => storage_path('app/articleImg'),
    public_path('assets') => storage_path('app/assets'),
    public_path('documentos') => storage_path('app/documentos'),
    public_path('eventosImg') => storage_path('app/eventosImg'),
],
```

Al disco de documentos por ejemplo puedo usarlo sin problemas. Pero el resto no me deja aparece el error:

**
Disk [local] does not have a configured driver.
**

Y yo quiero usar  articleImg, staffImg, etc...

En el controlador para almacenar la imagen uso lo siguiente:

```
$imageName = time().$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('articleImg',$imageName);
```

He probado ha rehacer los symbolic links varias veces, limpiar la cache, reiniciar pc y nada sigue igual.

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Te está diciendo que no tenes configurado el disco `local`. que es el que viene configurado por [default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/2254e8e301cfcbf8983c2f7cfa8b7c63549b73c7/config/filesystems.php#L16) en laravel, pero por lo que muestras, vos [lo eliminaste o no se ve en tus discos](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/2254e8e301cfcbf8983c2f7cfa8b7c63549b73c7/config/filesystems.php#L33).

Comment: Cuando haces `storeAs('articleImg',$imageName)` [el disco se pasa como tercer argumento opcional](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name), cosa que no estas haciendo, por lo que laravel va a intentar usar el que tengas por default, que es `local`: > `storeAs` method, which receives the path, the filename, and the (optional) disk as its arguments